# Add a custom field to a quiz

Tags: quiz, 7

I've got a quiz. There is a content type to create a question. I've added a textfield to it (which will show a link to where the user can find the answer).

When I look at the question itself the textfield has been added and is being displayed on the screen. But when the question is part of the quiz, the textfield isn't there anymore (not on the screen, nor in the code).

Who can help me?

Maybe I need to add some kind of hook to the [Quiz](http://drupal.org/project/quiz) module but I don't know how hooks/custom modules work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With https://www.drupal.org/project/quizz, you can add custom fields to answer entity.

https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/uploads-au.hipchat.com/36134/251454/2dGpAj2S1VWNJdg/True_false_question___Site-Install.png

Answer (score 1):

There are probably many ways doing this. I'm still new as well, so go easy on me.

I would suggest you to create a taxonomy `quiz`. Each list item of `quiz` would be your question. Then for the content type `answer`, have a field named `question` and select `term reference`, choose select list as the widget type. That way, when a user create a new content `answer` and refer to one of the question from taxonomy `quiz`, you can just click on the `question` and it will give you a list of `answer`.

Other ways would be using [Node Reference](http://drupal.org/project/references), but I couldn't get my mind around how to refer back to the question itself, maybe [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation) would do the trick.

But try my first suggestion first.

Answer (score 0):

I think your custom field is not appeared in the question form of the Quiz. The path is, for example, **node/8/take**. It is a custom form/page created by the [Quiz](http://drupal.org/project/quiz) module.

You would need to alter the form using [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) from your custom module. Then you would need to load the node (question) to get the field value using [node_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load/7) and add it to the form using `#markup` attribute.

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, &$form_id){
    if($form_id == 'quiz_question_answering_form'){
        $qnode = node_load($form['question_nid']['#value']);
        $form['link2answer'] = array(
            '#markup' => l('See answer', $qnode->field_link2answer['und'][0]['safe_value']),
        );
    }
}
```

If you don't know how to create a custom module, check [the documentation](http://drupal.org/node/361112).

Answer (score 0):

With quiz 7.x-5.0-alpha4+72-dev the array structure has changed somewhat. You will want to use this code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()
 */
function my_module_form_quiz_question_answering_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Print custom fields on the question page during the quiz.
  foreach ($form['questions'] as $node_key => $node_value) {
    $qnode = node_load($form['questions'][$node_key]['header']['body']['#object']->nid);
  }

  $field_source_url = !empty($qnode->field_source[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['url']) ? $qnode->field_source[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['url'] : '';
  $field_source_title = !empty($qnode->field_source[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['title']) ? $qnode->field_source[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['title'] : $field_source_url;
  $field_source = l($field_source_title, $field_source_url);

  $form['navigation']['#prefix'] = theme('question_link', array(
    'field_source' => $field_source,
  ));
}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme()
 *
 * @return array
 */
function my_module_theme() {
  $items = array();
  $theme_path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'my_theme') . '/templates';

  $items['question_link'] = array(
    'path' => $theme_path,
    'template' => 'question-link',
    'variables' => array(
      'field_source' => NULL,
    ),
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Then in sites/all/themes/my_theme/templates/question-link.tpl.php

```
<?php if($field_source): ?>
  <strong>Source field</strong>
  <div class="question-field-source"><?php print $field_source; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Clear the cache to alert Drupal of the new template file.